# A Circular Puzzle

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

The first step is to figure out the puzzle.

```
To Puzzling have     the I ready,
for a rising         year needed. old
man's home falling   wealth. a rhyme.
To look two          answers between Last.

all Stack swiftly    on Exchange. gotten
the puzzle. a        new Tasks: surprise!
symbol of bridge,    of crowns. children's
find within words;   the route: First.
```

A few words:

> Pink  Monarch  Drama  Butterfly  Horror  Velvet

Hint:

> 8/11

Answer (score 6):

## Partial Answer

If you read

> "circularly", taking the first word from the top left and going counterclockwise,

you get:

> To all on the Puzzling Stack Exchange I have swiftly gotten ready for the new year a puzzle. Tasks: needed. rising a Surprise! old man's symbol of wealth. home of crowns. a falling bridge, children's rhyme To find the answers look within route: between two words; First. Last.

This *almost* makes sense - I suspect some sort of mistake in the second row.

Comment: Sorry about that, my words were slightly wrong. Though the next part may be cryptic.

Comment: @GenericUser: But the punctuation and capitalization is correct?

Comment: Now it is, the periods tripped up autocorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, use the method described in [Deusovi's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47606/5373) to rearrange the words as follows (now with amended punctuation):

> To all on the
>  Puzzling Stack Exchange. I
>  have swiftly gotten ready,
>  for the new year
>  a puzzle. Tasks: needed.
>  rising a surprise! old
>  man's symbol of wealth.
>  home of crowns. a
>  falling bridge, children's rhyme.
>  To find the answers
>  look within route: between
>  two words; First. Last.

Editing out the flavour text, we have the following elements of the puzzle:

1. > needed.
2. > rising a surprise!
3. > old man's symbol of wealth.
4. > home of crowns.
5. > a falling bridge, children's rhyme.

and then

> looking within a "route", between the first and last words.

Clue 5 must refer to

> [LONDON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Bridge_Is_Falling_Down),

and clue 4 sounds like

> PALACE.

This makes me think that the other clues may give something like

> [BUCKINGHAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_Palace) or [CRYSTAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crystal_Palace) or [ST. JAMES'S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_James's_Palace),

in order for the whole phrase to make sense.

Comment: There's only 4 clues, though, in the lines. 5 if you find the way to format the answers. London is only part of that answer.